# Drift velocity of electrons how electrons drift

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

When no external electric field is applied, electrons move with thermal velocity and return to their initial position so displacement is zero. However, when an external electric field is applied, instead of moving back to their initial positions, do they drift little rightwards from their initial position? For example, if the initial position was $A$, then when there is an electric field applied, do they drift towards $B$ instead of going back to $A$?

Is this an accurate description of the phenomenon?

Comment: [One of a number of animations on the Internet](https://iwant2study.org/lookangejss/05electricitynmagnetism_17current/ejss_model_driftvelocity/driftvelocity_Simulation.xhtml)